# Metaplex Transfer pNFT failing

Tags: metaplex, spl-token-program

I am trying to transfer a pNFT via an anchor program, but it is failing at the `TokenProgram`.

Logs below

[image]

Comment: Can you please: 1) paste the error logs instead of a screenshot and 2) provide the serialized tx to simulate on https://explorer.solana.com/tx/inspector

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you're calling the instruction with the destination token account being the same as the source token account.

Answer (score 0):

As Serban pointed out in the comments, it is because the `destination token account` is the same as the `origin token account`

Changing it to a new address fixed this.

Though I am not satisfied with this answer because sending the same token to myself using Phantom wallet worked.